# C# Simple Poker Game - Is a good Design?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

I want to make a simple poker game.

What I pay particular attention to is design:

I look for suggestions to improve the quality of the design and also suggestions on possible improvements in style and logic.

Now the code that working good :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Poker_Calc_EnglishVersion
{
  public enum Suit
  {
    Hearts = 0,
    Diamonds,
    Clubs,
    Spades
  };

  public enum Value
  {
    A = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    T,
    J,
    Q,
    K
  };

  public class Card
  {
    public Suit Suid { get; }
    public Value Value { get; }



    public Card(Value value, Suit suit)
    {
        Value = value;
        Suid = suit;
    }



    public override string ToString()
    {
        //return base.ToString()+ " Value: " + Value + " Suit: " + Suid;

        return " Value: " + Value + " Suit: " + Suid;
    }
 }
```

Deck :

```
public class Deck
{

    private List<Card> _deck;
    public int _deckDimension { get; }

    public Deck()
    {
        this._deckDimension = 52;
        this._deck = new List<Card>(_deckDimension);

        foreach (Suit s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            foreach (Value v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Value)))
            {
                Card c = new Card(v, s);
                _deck.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }


    public Card GetCard(int i)
    {
        if (!(i >= 0 && i < _deckDimension))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return _deck[i];
    }

    public Card RemoveCard(int pos)
    {
        if (!(pos >= 0 && pos < _deckDimension))
        {
            return null;
        }

        Card cd_return = GetCard(pos);
        _deck.RemoveAt(pos);

        return cd_return;
    }


    public void SwapCard(int a, int b)
    {
        Card cd = GetCard(a);
        _deck[a] = GetCard(b);
        _deck[b] = cd;

    }
```

Dealer :

```
public class Dealer
{
    private Deck _deck;

    public Dealer(Deck deck)
    {
        this._deck = deck;
    }


    public bool Shuffle()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        int i = 0;

        int first;
        int second;

        while (i < 10000)
        {
            first = rnd.Next(0, _deck._deckDimension - 1);
            do
            {
                second = rnd.Next(0, _deck._deckDimension - 1);
            }
            while (first == second);

            _deck.SwapCard(first, second);
            i++;
        }

        return true;
    }


    public Card DealCard()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int first;
        first = rnd.Next(0, _deck._deckDimension - 1);

        return _deck.RemoveCard(first);

    }
```

Player

```
public class Player
{
    private float _stack { get; }
    private List<Card> _hand { get; }

    public Player()
    {
        _hand = new List<Card>(2);
    }


    public void ReceiveCard(Card c)
    {
        _hand.Add(c);
    }


    public List<Card> GetHand()
    {
        return _hand;
    }
```

Button1 and some listbox for testing and see result

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Deck deck = new Deck();

        deck.PrintDeck(listBox1);

        Dealer dl = new Dealer(deck);

        dl.Shuffle();

        deck.PrintDeck(listBox2);

        label1.Text = deck._deckDimension.ToString();

        dl.OrderDeck();

        deck.PrintDeck(listBox3);

        Player p1 = new Player();

        p1.ReceiveCard(dl.DealCard());
        //thread.sleep use for switch context and random generate not a two consecutive card
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        p1.ReceiveCard(dl.DealCard());

        p1.PrintHand(listBox4);


    }
```

There are some methods like *PrintDeck()* and *Order()* that I have created only for testing..

I know there is a "Fisher Yates" algorithm for *Shuffle()* 
I will implement it later.

How would you improve this code? How would you change the class design??

I have repeatedly asked myself if it makes sense to create a *Hand* class with two fields *Card*.

It makes sense because it is part of the context we are "modeling" 
and could contain the logic for the comparison (Hand valuation)

I await advice and opinions about it and for the general improvement of the code.

The next step is

- Create a functionality for distribute a Flop, Turn and River
- Create a functionality for Hand Valuation
- Create a functionality for Calculate odds when player goes all in before river coming
- And so on ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deck**

In both methods, `GetCard()` and `RemoveCard()`, the method-argument-validation is hard to read at first glance. You should change the condition and maybe extract the validation into its own method.

Having the condition like this

```
public Card GetCard(int i)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= _deckDimension)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return _deck[i];
}
```

is much easier to read. But wait, `_deckDimension` isn't a field, its a property and therfor it should **not** be named using underscore-prefix. Based on the .NET Naming Guidelines methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing. `_deckDimension` -> `DeckDimension`.

But still, this doesn't look right. If the validation fails the methods shouldn't return `null` but throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Looking at `RemoveCard()` I think you really should read the [.NET Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines?redirectedfrom=MSDN). In .NET one shouldn't use `snake_case` casing for naming things and shouldn't use abbreviations  like e.g `cd_return`. Why don't you name it `card`?

**Dealer**

You are passing the `Deck` into the constructor, which is a good thing, but, because you don't change the `_deck` you should make it `readonly`.

The `Random` class in .NET Framework isn't that random. If you call e.g the `Shuffle()` method very often and fast, it is possible to get the same random values over and over again. This is because `Random` when [instantiated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#instantiating-the-random-number-generator) will use the system clock to provide a seed value. You should have one `Random` object as a class-level field which should be instantiated in the constructor or directly.

The second argument of [`Random.Next(int, int)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is the **exclusive** upper bound of the random number to be returned. By calling `.Next(0, _deck._deckDimension - 1` you get `0 <= number < 51` but you want the card with number `51` as well, don't you? Thats true for `DealCard()` as well.

Making `Shuffle()` `void` would be good as well. I can't think of a way that shuffeling could fail, at least for a computer-dealer. A human could throw the cards on the ground, a computer wouldn't be so clumsy.

Its possible that `DealCard()` throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in its current implementation. Let us assume we call `DealCard()` the first time and the call to `Randum.Next()` returns `1` you return the second `Card` in `_deck`. Calling `DealCard()` again, the call to `Randum.Next()` returns `1` again, no problem you return the second `Card` in `_deck` again. The third call to `DealCard` results in `Random.Next()` returning `51` but you only have `50` cards left in the deck, resulting in the said exception in `Deck.GetCard()`.

To prevent this to happen we need to adjust the validation inside `GetCard()` and `RemoveCard()`. Instead of checking `_deckDimension` we should check against `_deck.Count` like so

```
public Card GetCard(int i)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= _deck.Count || _deck.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(i));
    }
    return _deck[i];
}
```

and change the call to `Random.Next()` in `DealCard` like so

```
first = rnd.Next(0, _deck.Count);
```

You can declare and initialize a variable on the same line. E.g in `DealCard()` you have

```
int first;
first = rnd.Next(0, _deck._deckDimension - 1);
```

which should be changed to

```
int first = rnd.Next(0, _deck._deckDimension - 1);
```

I just wanted to write that you should use `var` instead of the concrete type in `DealCard()` but had a quick glance at `Shuffle()` again where you used `var`. The rule of thumb for everything is **be consistent**. Choose **one** style and stick to it.

Use either `var rnd = new Random();` or `Random rnd = new Random();` but **don't use both**.

Comment: Ty @Heslacher :) Do you have a suggestions about the design ? 
Do you have a tip for me for improve a check on _Swap()_ ,_RemoveCard()_ and _Shuffle()_? _Shuffle_ return always true without check, isn't a good. 
For example , make sense to control the number of card in _RemoveCard() before method return ?  
how to check that the card was actually removed? 
How would you improve these parts?

Comment: because in the **_deck** there is 52 **Card**. From 0 to 51...

Comment: I have edit **Deck** class. Now there is only 'List<Card> _deck' such as field. Not others.
I have implements a property without a field ' public int Dimension        {
            get { return _deck.Count; }
        } ' . Is corret to have a one property without a field ?? I don't know but is a obtain value by '_deck.Count'.  
Now I continue to use in **Dealer** class '_deck.Dimension -1 ' for check in 'Shuffle() ' and ' DealCard() ' methods
but now shouldn't be problems with an 'OutOfRange' ...
What do you think about this solution ?? 
ty!
@Heslacher

Comment: Please work a little bit longer on your application meaning make it more finished and then come here again and ask a new question.